# Java XMLDecoder reading file into arraylist and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, xml

good day, Im trying to create a program that reads a XML file then puts it into an arrayList and displays each name. The output is blank, there no names appearing, how do read the objects in the file when its a string and how can I get the names of the XML into the array?

```
import java.beans.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException;
public class ReadNamesFromXML
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


        try {
            XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(new
                    FileInputStream("lab10.xml")); 

            ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>(); 
            System.out.println(names); 
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Not found"); 
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Not found"); 
        }
    }
}
```

XMl file:

```
<java version="1.8.0_144" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
<string>Harry</string>
<string>Ron</string>
<string>Hermione</string>
<string>Luna</string>
<string>Draco</string>
<string>Neville</string>
<string>Seamus</string>
<string>Ginny</string>
<string>Fred</string>
<string>George</string>
</java>
```

Comment: `names` is empty as you don't write anything to it

Comment: how can i get the names from the XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question description says *"Output is blank"*, in order to get the output into list you need to do following modification in your code.

1. You need to read the data from your xml file using `decoder.readObject();`, this will return you an Object, so type cast it to `String` and add into your `ArrayList`.
2. When `decoder.readObject();` is done with reading and adding everything into `ArrayList`, it will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, there change the message to *"All added to list"* instead of *"Not found"*, and say *ok*, once you clicked *ok* then it print your List on console with all names.
3. Also, it is a good practice to close all your `streams` once your program is terminating, for that you could use a `finally` block.

   ```
   public static void main(String... args) {

       XMLDecoder decoder = null;
       ArrayList<String> names = null;
       String s = null;
       try {
           decoder = new XMLDecoder(new
                   FileInputStream("lab10.xml")); 
           names = new ArrayList<>(); 
           do {
                s = (String)decoder.readObject();
                names.add(s);
           } while(null != s);
       }
       catch (FileNotFoundException e){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Not found"); 
       }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"All added to list"); 
       }
       finally {
           System.out.println(names); 
           decoder.close();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: @Anj26Pro, could you check this, here you do need to change your xml.

Comment: It's not idiomatic to use XMLDecoder in this way. I'd recommend you consider another XML parser.

Comment: @slesh, this is as per OP, he wants to use XMLDecoder, and even not want to change his XML.

Comment: @slesh, could you please change your downvote on my answer?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of your answer, really helped me understand it more and thanks for the tip to close all of the streams.

Answer (score 0):

To do it using [XMLDecoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/XMLDecoder.html), XML should have a format created by XMLEncoder for this particular object:

> The XMLDecoder class is used to read XML documents created using the XMLEncoder and is used just like the ObjectInputStream. For example, one can use the following fragment to read the first object defined in an XML document written by the XMLEncoder class:

In your case, XML should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.8.0_242" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
 <object class="java.util.ArrayList">
  <void method="add">
   <string>Harry</string>
  </void>
  <void method="add">
   <string>Hermione</string>
  </void>
  <void method="add">
   <string>Ron</string>
  </void>
 </object>
</java>
```

When you will have such file, you may read it using this code:

```
try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("lab10.xml");
             XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(inputStream)) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
            List<String> names = (List<String>) decoder.readObject();
            System.out.println(names);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException | IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not found");
        }
```

Seems that XMLEncoder is not what you need as you cannot provide the correct XML format. I'd rather consider you to use XMLDocument:

```
try {
            final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            final Document document = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse("lab10.xml");
            final NodeList strings = document.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("string");
            final List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(strings.getLength());
            for (int i = 0; i < strings.getLength(); i++) {
                names.add(strings.item(i).getTextContent());
            }
            System.out.println(names);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException | IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not found");
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I cannot change the XML file.